# How to prevent app from entering standby?

Tags: android

I need some help to keep my application alive in idle mode, but with no success. My application needs to retrieve some information from a server every 10 seconds and I cannot use FCM because the server is already created and cannot be changed. I also cannot use AlarmManager or JobScheduler because of the 10 seconds interval. I also made a test application which every second vibrates, increments a value every second and shows the current value, still with no success. So far I tried:

- Add the application to the "Not allowed" list in Battery optimization settings, first manually then by requesting the appropriate permission and showing the requested popup. This seems not no have effect, the application behaves identically if optimizations are allowed.
- Acquire a partial wake lock in the main activity, in the service then in both places.
- Use a background thread. First with a timer, then with just a while loop. The application seems to go to sleep 15 seconds after being sent to background, even though the device was still active. It would also go to sleep 15 seconds after pressing the power button, if it was in foreground at that moment.
- Use a background service (first bound, then not bound). First with a timer, then with a separate thread with a while loop. The application stops running after 15 seconds if is sent to background while the device is active or the device is sent to idle state (power button pressed). Vibrations stop immediately in both cases.
- Make the above service a foreground one. The differences from a background service are that application runs for 45 seconds in background (still 15 seconds with the device in idle mode) and the vibrations are active while the application runs.
  In simulator it works fine if I unplug the battery and send force-idle command from ADB, also on a real device in the same situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the answer. Apparently, some manufacturers are not happy with the battery optimization techniques in the Android, and added their own. In my case, on two Huawei devices with Android 9 and 10 and a Samsung device with Android 11 I found the same settings page, **Optimize battery usage**, with a field named **App launch** which let the user control if the application may run in background (by default this is managed automatically). After changing this, my application runs in idle mode if a foreground service is started. I did not find this settings page in the device emulators, nor in the documentation, which confirms it's a manufacturer setting.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this without additional permissions required would be to add `android:keepScreenOn="true"` to the view that needs to keep awake. Like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can also use flag `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` in activity to keep screen on.

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
    }
}
```

For more information, you can learn more about [Keep device awake](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock) in the document.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I don't want to keep the screen on, I just want the application to notify the user when there is new data on server. The device will stay in a pocket, so keeping the screen on is not desired. I already tried the advices in the link you provided, except for WakefulBroadcastReceiver, which is deprecated.